# The name XXXX does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();


    string strRadio = Utils.ReadFile(strTemp + @"\rstations.txt");
    string[] aRadio = strRadio.Split(new string[] { "#" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);    
    for (int i = 0; i < aRadio.Length; i += 2)
    {
       listBox.Items.Add(aRadio[i]);
    }

}

private void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = listBox.SelectedIndex;
    MessageBox.Show(aRadio[(index+1)]);
}
```

Now the error is `The name 'aRadio' does not exist in the current context`. Which comes from `MessageBox.Show(aRadio[(index+1)]);`. Do I need to declare the `aRadio` as public or something? If so, how would this be done?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're declaring `aRadio` as a local variable within your constructor. You need to declare it as an *instance* variable, and just assign it a value within your constructor:

```
// TODO: Give this a better name
private readonly string[] aRadio;

// TODO: Give your form a better name too
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // TODO: You might want to reconsider reading files in a GUI constructor, too
    // TODO: Use Path.Combine(strTemp, "rstations.txt" instead of concatenation
    string strRadio = Utils.ReadFile(strTemp + @"\rstations.txt");
    aRadio = strRadio.Split(new string[] { "#" },
                            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    for (int i = 0; i < aRadio.Length; i += 2)
    {
       listBox.Items.Add(aRadio[i]);
    }
}
```

I wouldn't be surprised if you could do rather better than this approach though, by adding a custom object (or just a `KeyValuePair<string, string>`) to the list box and binding the display part through properties. That way you could get the selected *item* rather than the selected index... there's no need to keep text/value pairs like this.

Comment: Could you elaborate yourself on the additional comments you posted? Where would you want to read files? On another thread?

Comment: @Devator: Probably on start-up in some entirely separate code, while a splash-screen is showing. It really depends on the rest of the application.

Comment: You should use `Path.Combine`

Comment: @user: Have added a "TODO" - I wanted to keep the original code close in general.

Answer (score 2):

```
   private string[] aRadio;

    public Form1() { 
      InitializeComponent();       
      string strRadio = Utils.ReadFile(strTemp + @"\rstations.txt");
      this.aRadio = strRadio.Split(new string[] { "#" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
      for (int i = 0; i < aRadio.Length; i += 2)
      {
        listBox.Items.Add(aRadio[i]);
      }
    }

    private void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      int index = listBox.SelectedIndex;
      MessageBox.Show(this.aRadio[(index+1)]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you're to access to a variable defined in the domain of your contructor `form1` so you could do this

```
//Define the variable as an attribute of class

private string[] strRadio;
public Form1()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        string strRadio = Utils.ReadFile(strTemp + @"\rstations.txt");
        aRadio = strRadio.Split(new string[] { "#" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        for (int i = 0; i < aRadio.Length; i += 2)
        {
           listBox.Items.Add(aRadio[i]);
        }

    }

    private void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = listBox.SelectedIndex;
        MessageBox.Show(aRadio[(index+1)]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't recommend public fields like this :(

Answer (score -3):

System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries : typed out in this manner will solve your problem.

Don't ask me why I just know it works this way.